# Software connection abort: socket write error Tomcat8

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat8, maven-tomcat-plugin

So i'm trying to deploy my war to tomcat8 server, first i start tomcat by **startup.bat**

```
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.j
ava:396)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.j
ava:338)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:67)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:18
7)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 20
16.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\logs\manager.2018-09-28.log (Access denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:383)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:96)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLo
gManager.java:563)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLo
gManager.java:506)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLo
gManager.java:309)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.j
ava:396)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.j
ava:338)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:67)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:18
7)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 20
16.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\logs\host-manager.2018-09-28.log (Access denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:383)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:96)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLo
gManager.java:563)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLo
gManager.java:506)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLo
gManager.java:309)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.j
ava:396)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.j
ava:338)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:67)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:18
7)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.383 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Server built:          Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.383 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Server number:         8.5.11.0
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.384 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.385 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log OS Version:            6.1
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.386 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Architecture:          amd64
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.387 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\jre
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.388 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_72-b15
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.389 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.390 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.391 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.392 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\conf\logging.proper
ties
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.392 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.Cl
assLoaderLogManager
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.394 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.394 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catali
na.webresources
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrai
ns\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrai
ns\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerLi
stener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBra
ins\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\temp
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListen
er.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.10 using APR
 version 1.5.2.
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.398 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListen
er.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters
 [false], random [true].
28-Sep-2018 17:35:53.399 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListen
er.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL
 [true]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.299 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListen
er.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016)
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.480 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini
tializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.597 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.
getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.602 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Ini
tializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.608 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.
getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.609 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load I
nitialization processed in 1789 ms
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.st
artInternal Starting service Catalina
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.653 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.sta
rtInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.661 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start
up.HostConfig.beforeStart Unable to create directory for deployment: C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\conf\Catalina\lo
calhost
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.664 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.valve
s.AccessLogValve.open Failed to open access log file [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jet
Brains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\logs\localhost_access_log.2018-
09-28.txt]
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2
016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\logs\localhost_access_log.2018-09-28.txt (╬Єърчрэю т
фюёЄєях)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open(AccessLogValve.java:58
5)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.startInternal(AccessLogValv
e.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipel
ine.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.ja
va:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java
:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.670 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program File
s (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\docs
28-Sep-2018 17:35:54.740 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.cor
e.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\lo
calhost\docs] for context [/docs]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.289 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.S
essionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for s
ession ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [222] milliseconds.
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.309 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.Embedd
edServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jet
Brains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\localhost\docs is
 unusable.
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.329 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\docs has
 finished in 659 ms
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.332 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program File
s (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\examples
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.349 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.cor
e.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\lo
calhost\examples] for context [/examples]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.859 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.Embedd
edServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jet
Brains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\localhost\example
s is unusable.
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.862 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\examples
 has finished in 530 ms
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.862 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program File
s (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\host-manager

28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.879 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.cor
e.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\lo
calhost\host-manager] for context [/host-manager]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.906 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.Embedd
edServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jet
Brains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\localhost\host-ma
nager is unusable.
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.908 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\host-man
ager has finished in 46 ms
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.908 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program File
s (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\manager
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.914 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.cor
e.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\lo
calhost\manager] for context [/manager]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.944 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.Embedd
edServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jet
Brains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\localhost\manager
 is unusable.
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.946 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\manager
has finished in 38 ms
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.947 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program File
s (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\ROOT
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.952 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.cor
e.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\lo
calhost\ROOT] for context []
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.980 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.Embedd
edServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jet
Brains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\work\Catalina\localhost\ROOT is
 unusable.
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.982 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program
Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\webapps\ROOT has
 finished in 35 ms
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.987 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:55.998 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
28-Sep-2018 17:35:56.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start
Server startup in 1393 ms
```

after using mvn tomcat7:deploy

```
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ diploma ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/Student Rating
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FStudent+Rating&upda
te=true
2100/33559 KB
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request:
Software caused connection abort: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FStudent+Rating&upda
te=true
2100/33559 KB
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request:
Software caused connection abort: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FStudent+Rating&upda
te=true
2100/33559 KB
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request:
Software caused connection abort: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FStudent+Rating&upda
te=true
2100/33559 KB
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.237 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-28T16:59:28+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:
deploy (default-cli) on project diploma: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Software
caused connection abort: socket write error -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

**tomcat-users.xml**

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
```

Maven settings
**settings.xml**

```
      <server>
            <id>TomcatServer</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>password</password>
    </server>
```

POM
**pom.xml**

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/Student Rating</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

As result when i open localhost:8080 i have HTTP status 404 and i'm unable to deploy my artifact.
I have no idea hov to fix this and why this problem happens.

Comment: I suspect your log foder is empty. Create access log file and more importantly create catalina.out file in your tomcat log directory. Or chances are there that startup.bat file doesnt have enough rights to create those file in log dir. So start it with admin rights.

Comment: thanks i resolve problem with localhost but with remote tomcat server it still remain